# I am getting Error Number: 1064 while updatin data into mysql,

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and i just want update a single value in database using following query;

```
$this->db->query('UPDATE order SET status="1" WHERE orderid="$id";');
```

but i getting following error.

> Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order SET status="1" WHERE orderid="$id"' at line 1

```
UPDATE order SET status="1" WHERE orderid="$id";

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\oshop\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Comment: `$this->db->query("UPDATE order SET status=1 WHERE orderid='$id'");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word, therefore it must be quoted:

```
$this->db->query('UPDATE `order` SET status="1" WHERE orderid="$id";');
                         ^-----^
```

Relevant doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html